# The value of variable differrent when using var_dump()

Tags: php, csv, import, var-dump

I have a function to insert CSV files to database. My project using Yii Framework, but this class not related Yii.

I import successly, but I have a trouble when print the number of line imported.

My class (multiple files, but there is only 1 file):

```
class LsuController extends BackEndController {
    public function dbconfig(){
        $dbconfig = array();
        $dbconfig['dsn'] = 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=bs_dev_csueastbay';
        $dbconfig['username'] = 'root';
        $dbconfig['password'] = '';
        return $db = new PDO($dbconfig['dsn'], $dbconfig['username'], $dbconfig['password']);
    }

    public function actionIndex() {
        // Config database
        $db = $this->dbconfig();

        $has_err = 0;
        $link = dirname(__FILE__)."/../../../runtime/Import/";
        $handles = array();
        $handles[] = fopen($link."bookPictureMappings.csv","r");

        foreach ($handles as $handle) {
            if(!$handle){
                $has_err++;
            }
        }
        if($has_err == 0){
            foreach ($handles as $key=>$handle) {
                switch ($key) {
                    case '0':
                    $i = 0;
                    $model_err = 0; $ss = 0;
                    do { 
                        if (isset($data[0])) {
                            if($i > 0){
                                $sql="INSERT INTO bookpicturemappings (Id, BookId, PictureId, bookpicturemappings.Order) VALUES (
                                    :Id, :BookId, :PictureId, :bookOrder)";

                                $command = $db->prepare($sql);
                                $command->bindParam(":Id",$data[0],PDO::PARAM_STR);
                                $command->bindParam(":BookId",$data[1],PDO::PARAM_STR);
                                $command->bindParam(":PictureId",$data[2],PDO::PARAM_STR);
                                $command->bindParam(":bookOrder",$data[3],PDO::PARAM_STR);

                                if ($command->execute()){
                                    $ss++;
                                }
                            }
                            $i++;
                        } 
                    } while ($data = fgetcsv($handle,0,",","\""));

                    echo "Insert bookpicturemappings.csv successful! Total: ".($i-1)." - Import: ".$ss." - Error: ".$model_err."<br>";
                    break;
...............................
```

The issue in here:

- When the code run, the result is ($ss = 0):

> Insert bookpicturemappings.csv successful! Total: 1862 - Import: 0 -
>   Error: 0

- When I add var_dump() funtion:

> ```
> if ($command->execute()){
>       $ss++;
> }
> var_dump($ss);
> ```

the result is ($ss = 1862):

> <...value dump....>
>
> Insert bookpicturemappings.csv successful! Total: 1862 - Import: 1862
>   - Error: 0

WT...? I do not understand why?

Comment: Try add ERRMODE_EXCEPTION (http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.setattribute.php) and show us result, probably your PDO query not run correct.

Answer (score 0):

Check your latest item in $handles, my guess it's empty (newline at end of file?) And $ss is set to 0 but does not loop.

**edit**

Your last iteration is false, but the condition is only checked after executing the block.

Try to ditch the do and use the while like this:

```
while ($data = fgetcsv($handle,0,",","\"")){ 
    if (isset($data[0])) {
        if($i > 0){
            $sql="INSERT INTO bookpicturemappings (Id, BookId, PictureId, bookpicturemappings.Order) VALUES ( :Id, :BookId, :PictureId, :bookOrder)";
            $command = $db->prepare($sql);
            $command->bindParam(":Id",$data[0],PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $command->bindParam(":BookId",$data[1],PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $command->bindParam(":PictureId",$data[2],PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $command->bindParam(":bookOrder",$data[3],PDO::PARAM_STR);
            if ($command->execute()){
                $ss++;
            }
        }
        $i++;
    }
};
```

Comment: The latest item not empty, and I echo $ss in a item.

Comment: Does your final $handle get executed?

Comment: Check http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.do.while.php it says: except the truth expression is checked at the end of each iteration instead of in the beginning. Try a while without a  'do'.

Comment: There is another potential flaw: in the first iteration $i equals zero. That means your first statement will not get executed. Unless of course the first line should be ignored.